# How do you run an executable with the same name as an alias in powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell

[sc.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) is a command line tool for manipulating services on windows. E.g. to list all the services on your machine you can type `sc query` from a command prompt. However, if you do it from powershell, it instead executes [Set-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347736.aspx) because sc is an alias for Set-Content. Even `& sc` will execute the alias.

How do I run sc.exe from a powershell prompt?

Comment: I ran into the same problem trying to run `where` to determine the directory of an exe in the system Path. The conflicting alias was `where` -> `Where-Object`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options, you can either use `cmd /c sc query` or `sc.exe query`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what Justin answered or you can create your own alias for the command. it depends if you need to use the command often throughout a session. If you don't, just listen to Justin. If you do, aliasing isn't a bad idea.

Locate the `sc.exe` executable that you would like to use. (We'll assume it's in the root of your C:\ drive for now.)

Create the PowerShell alias with the following command:

```
Set-Alias <What you want to use as an alias> <Path to executable or one of the commands Justin proposed>
```

For example:

```
Set-Alias sc2 "C:\cs.exe"
```

These aliases will disappear when you close PowerShell, export them like so:

```
Export-Alias "C:\Myaliases.txt"
```

Then import them when you need to use them (disregard all the errors that show, these errors are due to the fact that PowerShell tries to restore *all* aliases, including those that are built-in. Of course, these already exist so they are ignored.)

```
Import-Alias "C:\Myaliases.txt"
```

More documentation on PowerShell aliasing available on [MSTN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692685.aspx).

Comment: That's a good point. I edited you answer since sc comes with windows and you can use the systemroot environment variable to locate it.

Comment: @JustinDearing I don't see any (pending) edits... And I do get what you mean about the systemroot. However, not everyone who will come here will be looking for `sc` specific. Therefore, the answer is now applicable to other aliased executables as well. Built-in or not.

Comment: another great tip is, instead of running `Import-Alias` everytime, you can open your $PROFILE .ps1 file running:`code $PROFILE` (if you have VsCode installed), and paste the `Import-Alias "C:\Myaliases.txt"` inside it, so everytime you open your PS, it'll load automattically